# Compass: separate sprite declaration for IE8

Tags: compass-sass

In my .scss I'm using CSS3 pseudo classes. For example :

```
.btn:disabled {
  @include assets-sprites(btn_disabled);
}
.btn.disabled {
  @include assets-sprites(btn_disabled);
}
```

Compass combine these two declaration into one :

```
.btn:disabled, .btn.disabled {
  background: url("img/assets.png")
}
```

But Internet Explorer 8 doesn't read the declaration if a CSS3 pseudo class is present in the selector (like :disabled, :checked, :not, etc).

So how can I output this into something like that ?

```
.btn:disabled {
  background: url("img/assets.png")
}

.btn.disabled {
  background: url("img/assets.png")
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can combine placeholders and a mixin to manage this with a DRY approach:

#### SCSS

```
@import "compass";

// Generate separate CSS3 pseudo-selector / fallback selector.
//
// @param string $selector
//   The CSS3 selector name, without the first colon.
// @param string $sprite
//   The sprite name without the file extension.
@mixin sprite-css3-pseudo($selector, $sprite, $map: $assets-sprites) {
  // CSS3 selector
  &:#{$selector} {
    @extend %assets_css3-map;
    @include sprite-background-position($map, $sprite);
  }
  // IE8 fallback
  &.#{$selector} {
    @extend %assets-map;
    @include sprite-background-position($map, $sprite);
  }
}

// $<map>-sprite-base-class to customize the base class
// used when we importing the sprite map.
$assets-sprite-base-class: '%assets-map';

// Compass generates the following rule:
// %assets-map {
//   background: $assets-sprites no-repeat;
// }
@import "assets/*.png";

// We have to split the CSS3 selectors of the classic selectors (the
// fallback) so we need to declare a new placeholder with the same
// content generated by Compass for the base class.
%assets_css3-map {
  background: $assets-sprites no-repeat;
}

.btn {
  @include sprite-css3-pseudo('disabled', 'btn_disabled');
}
.fb {
  @include sprite-css3-pseudo('checked', 'fb_icon');
}

.icon-alarm {
  // We can still use the regular sprite generator
  @include assets-sprite('alarm');
  // And our mixin :)
  @include sprite-css3-pseudo('disabled', 'alarm');
}
```

#### CSS

```
.btn.disabled, .fb.checked, .icon-alarm, .icon-alarm.disabled {
  background: url('../images/assets-sacf5a47174.png') no-repeat;
}

.btn:disabled, .fb:checked, .icon-alarm:disabled {
  background: url('../images/assets-sacf5a47174.png') no-repeat;
}

.btn:disabled {
  background-position: 0 -224px;
}
.btn.disabled {
  background-position: 0 -224px;
}

.fb:checked {
  background-position: 0 -176px;
}
.fb.checked {
  background-position: 0 -176px;
}

.icon-alarm {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
.icon-alarm:disabled {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
.icon-alarm.disabled {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here'es the solution, thanks to @pascalduez:

```
$assets: sprite-map("assets/*.png");

.btn:disabled { background: sprite($assets, user); }
.btn.disabled { background: sprite($assets, user); }
```